# Django - StatReloader not updating when change html file

Tags: python, django, localhost

I'm running into an issue I havn't had before. When I run `python manage.py runserver` I get default message:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
November 02, 2021 - 12:57:41
Django version 3.2.8, using settings 'core.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
```

If I change some html and save changes, the changes are not shown in the browser. I have to quit the localserver and restart runserver to see the changes.

This problem just appears out of nowhere - does anyone know how to fix or is there a package to fix this issue?

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Are you running the cached template loader? because if you are you might want to disable it ...

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/api/#configuring-an-engine

Comment: @Phteven I added the TEMPLATES to the quesetion..

Comment: are you running DEBUG=True?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way

```
--reload-include '*.html'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).